# How to fill data from PreferenceScreen in Android?

Tags: android, android-preferences

I want use this library for change color : [Color Picker](https://github.com/yukuku/ambilwarna).  i use this library in `PrefrenceSreen` and i want change text color with this component! but show me error when start application.
**LogCat error :**

```
02-29 15:24:09.541 19631-19631/com.tellfa.mytestpreference E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.tellfa.mytestpreference, PID: 19631
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tellfa.mytestpreference/com.tellfa.mytestpreference.MainPage}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.tellfa.mytestpreference.AppPreference.getContentTextColor()' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.tellfa.mytestpreference.AppPreference.getContentTextColor()' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at com.tellfa.mytestpreference.MainPage.ContentTextColor(MainPage.java:66)
                                                                                 at com.tellfa.mytestpreference.MainPage.onCreate(MainPage.java:46)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6020)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

**AppPreference code :**

```
public class AppPreference {
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private Context context;

    private static final String KeyContentTextColor = "textColor_pref";

    public AppPreference(Context context){
        this.sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        this.editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        this.context = context;
    }

    public int getContentTextColor(){
        return sharedPreferences.getInt(KeyContentTextColor, context.getResources().getColor(R.color.textDark));
    }

    public void setContentTextColor(Integer res){
        editor.putInt(KeyContentTextColor, res);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

**Setting Page code :**

```
public class SettingPage extends PreferenceActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    private AppCompatDelegate mDelegate;
    private AppPreference myAppPreference;
    private Context context;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private AmbilWarnaPreference ContentTextColor_pref;
    private Preference defaultColor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getmDelegate().installViewFactory();
        getmDelegate().onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.toolbar_setting);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.setting_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_setting);
        //getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new myPreferenceFragment()).commit();

        this.context = this;
        this.myAppPreference = TestPreference.getAppPreference();

        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        pref.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

        ContentTextColor_pref = (AmbilWarnaPreference) findPreference("textColor_pref");
        defaultColor = findPreference("prefDefaultValues");
        defaultColor.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                myAppPreference.setContentTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textDark));
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

**Main Page code :**

```
public class MainPage extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private WebView webView;
    private TextView textView;
    private AppPreference appPreference;
    private Context context;
    private Activity activity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_page);

        this.appPreference = TestPreference.getAppPreference();
        this.activity = this;
        this.context = this;

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Main Page");
        }
        //toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_menu_toolbar);
        toolbar.setLogoDescription("Logo");
        toolbar.setTitle("Main Page");
        toolbar.setSubtitle("Home Page");
        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.main_manu);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_textView);
        textView.setTextColor(appPreference.getContentTextColor());
    }
```

**TestPreference code:**

```
public class TestPreference extends Application {
    private static AppPreference appPreference;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        appPreference = new AppPreference(this);
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public static AppPreference getAppPreference(){
        return appPreference;
    }
}
```

How to fix this problem? i really need help! thanks all <3

Comment: Please show Your TestPreference class....

Comment: and where are You calling getContentTextColor()? it´s not posted above, maybe some code snippet missing in your MainPage class?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs, update above post. please help me. i really need this

Comment: @Opiatefuchs, can you help me?

Comment: I guess that You have to call super.onCreate() BEFORE You are initializing Your appPreference in Your TestPreference class. It´s just an assumption. Try it, remove the app from Your device, clean Your project and install again after You have made the changes.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs, I did everything you said.But again show me an error

Comment: and your TestPreference is added to manifest?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs, TestPreference is class and this is no activity.not need defined in Manifest

Comment: fur sure you have to. Application is something like the master class of all inside an app. it must be declared in the manifest. Check here of how to use  Application class: https://www.mobomo.com/2011/05/how-to-use-application-object-of-android/

Comment: but by the way, it´s not clear for my why You are using Application class. As much I can see from Your code, You don´t need it...you can do the same thing by making a simple class....

Comment: @Opiatefuchs, woooooooow!!!your are great, it's ok . thaaaaaaaaaaaanks yourT added TestPreference in Manifest : android:name=".TestPreference" and ok. thanks my dear friend <3

Comment: And now it works? if yes, I will put it as answer to lead future questions of SO users into right direction....

Comment: @Opiatefuchs, yes it's ok. please add this help to answer other people.

Comment: glad that I could help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the Application class TestPreference to Your manifest. This class must be registerred to work correctly:

```
     <application 
    android:icon="@drawable/yourAppIcon"
    android:label="@string/yourAppName" 
    android:name="yourPackage.TestPreference">

              <!-- your other classes/services etc between application tag -->

</application>
```